# Need a bash script to replace static IP with a new IP address

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bash, scripting

I would like to have a bash script for Centos machine.
I want the script to show me the current IP Address /subnet mask / Default GW.
and give me option to enter a new IP Address /subnet Mask / Default GW.
It should do it for ETH0.

Can someone have an idea how to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: `system-config-network-tui` could probably do this. Any particular reason why it has to be a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write it all for you, but here's something that works in Ubuntu:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:" | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

That will echo the current ip address in eth0.

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig(1) is the standard command for manipulating IP parameters of interfaces.  See `man ifconfig` for how to use it, but e.g.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

will set the IP address and netmask for eth0.

To read the interface parameters, you can use grep/sed/perl to parse the output of `ifconfig eth0`, but if you have the ifdata command, a less painful way to get e.g. just the IP address is

```
ifdata -pa eth0
```

In Ubuntu, ifdata is part of the `moreutils` package.